# Lost metrics when using Spring Webflux Webclient with Jetty

Tags: jetty, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, micrometer, spring-micrometer

*What I would like to achieve:*

Get metrics when using Spring Webflux Webclient, but with Jetty HttpClient (instead of Netty)

*What I tried:*

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public WebClient getWebClient(final HttpClient httpClient) {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://some-host:8080/api/path")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .clientConnector(new JettyClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public HttpClient getHttpClient(final MeterRegistry registry) {
        final var sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();
        sslContextFactory.setSslContext(getCustomSSLContext());
        final var clientConnector = new ClientConnector();
        clientConnector.setSslContextFactory(sslContextFactory);
        final var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientTransportDynamic(clientConnector));
        return httpClient;
    }
```

with those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-elastic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-reactive-httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

*Issue:*

Unfortunately, I am not getting any Webflux Webclient related metrics, nor Jetty related metrics.

*Note:*

Just to test, I did try using Netty as such:

```
  @Bean
    @Primary
    public WebClient getWebClient(ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector) {
        return WebClient.create("http://somehost:9200")
                .mutate()
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ClientHttpConnector getClientHttpConnector(HttpClient httpClient) {
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        return HttpClient.create()
                .wiretap(true)
                .metrics(true, Function.identity())
                .protocol(HttpProtocol.HTTP11);
    }
```

And I do get some metrics, (question here, are they correct, or expected?)

```
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_active_direct_memory
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_active_heap_memory
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_chunk_size
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_direct_arenas
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_heap_arenas
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_normal_cache_size
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_small_cache_size
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_threadlocal_caches
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_used_direct_memory
reactor_netty_bytebuf_allocator_used_heap_memory
reactor_netty_connection_provider_active_connections
reactor_netty_connection_provider_idle_connections
reactor_netty_connection_provider_max_connections
reactor_netty_connection_provider_max_pending_connections
reactor_netty_connection_provider_pending_connections
reactor_netty_connection_provider_total_connections
reactor_netty_http_client_address_resolver
reactor_netty_http_client_connect_time
reactor_netty_http_client_data_received
reactor_netty_http_client_data_received_time
reactor_netty_http_client_data_sent
reactor_netty_http_client_data_sent_time
reactor_netty_http_client_response_time
reactor_netty_http_client_tls_handshake_time
```

However, I would like to use Jetty instead, and sadly, not getting any metrics.

*Question:*

What is the correct way to get Jetty and/or Webflux Webclient specific metrics please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the examples here use the `WebClient` instrumentation, but rather rely on the HTTP library instrumentation. In the case of Reactor Netty, [the library is instrumented directly with Micrometer](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_observability). This is not the case for the Jetty client.

Arguably, you should not need to do any of that, as `WebClient` itself is instrumented and provides metrics no matter which HTTP client library is used (Reactor Netty, Jetty, JDK).

[As explained in the Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.rest-client.webclient.customization), you should inject the `WebClient.Builder` instance that is auto-configured with your preferences already: JSON codecs, observability and more. In this case, the `ObservationRegistry` is automatically configured on the builder and you'll get [the metrics and traces contributed by Spring Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/observability.html#observability.http-client.webclient).

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    final var sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();
    sslContextFactory.setSslContext(getCustomSSLContext());
    final var clientConnector = new ClientConnector();
    clientConnector.setSslContextFactory(sslContextFactory);
    final var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientTransportDynamic(clientConnector));

    return builder
            .baseUrl("http://some-host:8080/api/path")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .clientConnector(new JettyClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .build();
}
```

If you would like lower-level metrics with the Jetty client, similar to what you get currently with Reactor Netty, please create an enhancement request on the Jetty project.